# ASP.NET MVC - ModelState.IsValid is false, how to bypass?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a small application where I am creating a customer

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer(GWCustomer customer)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.CustomerName))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CustomerName", "The name cannot be empty");
    }
    //...
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //insert in db
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `GWCustomer` object has an `Id`, which is primary key and cannot be null. This makes the validation framework flag it as an error. But it's not an error, I haven't created the customer yet, and for now is should be null until it gets saved. How do I bypass this? Or fix it?

I never get to insert it in the DB because the `ModelState` is never valid.

**Edit** I am using Linq to SQL, and a repository pattern.

Comment: You haven't given us any information about how you're actually validating.  You'll probably want to include this.  What validation framework?  What do the validation attributes/methods look like?

Comment: With the EntityFramework, you'd ask the model or DAO for a new default object, then fill in the data. In the Metske Design Patterns, it's called "Builder" whereas what you're trying is "Prototype". MVC might like that approach a bit more.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't explain anything about the "validation framework."  Linq to SQL and Repository Pattern are not validation frameworks.  Linq to SQL is an Object-Relational Mapper and the Repository Pattern is a CRUD abstraction.  Neither of these interact with the ModelState.  Where is the ID validation error actually coming from?  What class/component?  Where is the line of code that actually validates the ID?

Comment: The validation "framework" is what i show you in code. I do no more validation than this. The error with the ID is (as far as i can read) generated by the Linq2Sql dataContext because my Id is listed in the DB as "not null" - its an identity.

Comment: Linq to SQL does not interact with ModelState.  Something actually has to validate the ID and call `AddModelError`.  You aren't showing us the part that does that.  It doesn't look like you're even using *any* validation framework, you're doing it manually in the controller.  So where's the line of code that checks the `ID` property?  Or are you actually getting an exception somewhere?

Comment: @Aaronaught: DataAnnotations validation does it automatically. ID in his model has [Required] attribute defined, so it throws an error. H4mm3rHead didn't wrote validation code, it is in framework. Can be disabled but Bind attribute makes it work properly.

Comment: The only thing that interacts with this GWCustomer and the Id is the auto generated classes by the Linq2Sql - which i dont think i have any control over. I do not Use any particular validation framework, i do it manually in the controller - as i mentioned its a small solution. I have no other code to show!

Comment: Am I missing something essential about this? Seems like a lot of talk for me to explain myself!

Comment: @H4mm3rHead: As I wrote earlier. `Id` in your `GWCustomer` class has `RequiredAttribute` defined. Entity Framework looks at this attribute and automatically adds an error. Read about 'DataAnnotations' validation in MVC framework. You should propably use it, because adding model errors in controller is bad.

Comment: @LukLed: That's evident *now* after your answer was accepted, but at no point did the OP specify that he was using DataAnnotations or even MVC 2.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Forgive my ignorance, i thought that the fact that i wrote in the heading: "asp.net mvc" - made this obvious. And DataAnnotations - will look into these - dont know what they are. (If I knew i wouldnt have to ask my question)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This will exclude value from binding, but not validation:

```
public ActionResult CreateCustomer([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]GWCustomer customer)
```

Even when validation occurs, you can still correct ModelState by calling:

```
ModelState.Remove("Id");
```

It will remove entries related to Id and change `ModelState.Valid` property to true if only `Id` was causing errors.

Using data layer objects in view layer is not recommended. You should definitely think about creating dedicated view model, without `Id` field.

Comment: This is what you are looking for.

Comment: ModelState.Remove was exactly what I needed to save me from overriding attributes.  Thanks!

Comment: You're a life saver. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone ends up here looking for a way to completely turn off validation for a property, check out the [ValidateNever] attribute ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0)).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have this line in your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Delete it and the view won't send that parameter with the model.

Comment: But doesn't EF take an `Id` of `0` as a creation of a new Entity?

Answer (score 2):

This is why I always say that the ViewModel objects (input and output) should be separated from the Domain Objects.

The input model should be validated in the way you are above; the domain object state should be validated before it gets written to the database (and exceptions thrown if it is somehow invalid).

Comment: I have a repository pattern, my CRUD is in a seperate class, for doing the thing you describe. I am trying to validate my domain object, but it seems that the validation framework is messing with me. I think i did the seperation of domain object and input/output - "by the book"

Comment: @pdr I totally agree with this answer. Always bind to a viewmodel and not your domain objects. It's seperate logic. The accepted answer might solve the problem, but it's definately not best practice.